# Assigned property before inserted is not propogate up to parent context for saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I reviewed other SO questions like [Assigning NSManagedObject properties before insertion doesn't stick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550279/assigning-nsmanagedobject-properties-before-insertion-doesnt-stick). 
But that didn't solved my question. 
Let me explain my situation.

---

### Setup

I used nested NSManagedObjectContext

- writerContext linked to NSPersistentStoreCoordinate
- mainContext linked to writerContext with parentContext

---

I create object that has not been inserted by `- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context`
 and `[self initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];`.

Assign property before inserted `[mainContext insertObject:object]`, and
assign other properties after insertion and save to mainContext

---

### Consequence

Assigned property before insertion is filled in mainContext(`[mainContext objectWithID:objectID]`), but **nil** in writerContext(`[writerContext objectWithId:objectID]`).

---

The reason of this problem I suspect is that assinged property before insertion seems not to be marked as changed. Because if I update the property already assigned with other value after insertion, then it is not nil after saving and propogate up to writerContext.

**What is the problem in this situation and what should I do for fixing this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply insert the object into the context first and then assign its properties. If you must insert them before, you could read and assign them again before saving.

Comment: The reason why I defer insertion is that I don't want this object to be saved indirectly when saving other object. Other approach should be used in my situation?

Comment: You could maybe create another child context that you can throw away if you do not want to save it. You could also throw away changes with a `reset` at the right point. Technically, this is really trivial. Your problem is more about general app flow logic, I suspect. Perhaps you should go back to the design board and make a robust plan.

Comment: Creating child context is not fit to my solution because I should set relation to other object in parent context. But, You are right. I should redesign saving plan! Thanks!